# maven build fails for java 9 when java 11 is installed

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I'm trying to build the log4j package from source:

```
$ wget https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/archive/refs/tags/rel/2.14.1.tar.gz
$ tar -xf 2.14.1.tar.gz
$ cd logging-log4j2-rel-2.14.1/log4j-core
$ /apache-maven-3.8.4/bin/mvn compile 1>./temp.txt
$ grep "\[ERROR\] Failed.*java9.*" ./temp.txt | sed "s/: org/:\norg/g"
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project log4j-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.14.1:
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core-java9:zip:2.14.1 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

This is a bit weird because my java version is 11, what am I missing?

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: First why are you trying to build from source? Second you should use this location: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html (source) apart from that it does not make sense use the one which is provided by central repository ...furthermore why using such an old version... also the description how to build shows `mvn install`...

Comment: @khmarbaise I can't see infected version `2.14.1` there?

Comment: `mvn install` fails with the same error as `mvn compile`

Comment: If you want to get the binaries for version 2.14.1, just go to the [download page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html) given by @khmarbaise, click the [ASF archive repository](https://archive.apache.org/dist/logging/log4j/) link, then the 2.14.1 directory, and finally apache-log4j-2.14.1-bin.tar.gz.

Comment: @Olivier thanks, but I want to build the jars from source after editing them.

Comment: Why use the most recent release of Log4j 2.17.0...

Comment: I'm doing research on the infected log4j version ...

Comment: Versions before 2.15 are not "infected", they are vulnerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until recently, the build process of `log4j-core` depends on the build process of a companion `log4j-core-java9` module.

This multi-module build approach was introduced in [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2191) and the changes performed are described in [this commit](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/commit/46cdb7f470f4e0452fc662f97bad1f6e2a174e0d).

In a future version of the library these dependencies will be removed as described in [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3241) precisely to avoid potential dependency problems. The issue provides more information about was it going on:

> Log4j API and Log4j Core have to build the Java 9 classes in one
> Maven module and then copy them into the "normal" module. The Java
> 9 projects are not deployed during a release. The pom.xml files
> were specifying both as provided dependencies. When the enforcer
> plugin sees this it is trying to resolve them - sometimes - and
> fails. It seems these don't need to be declared as dependencies
> because they are configured into the dependency plugin. So the
> dependencies should be removed from the pom files.

If you need to build the code from an older version from source, according to the changes introduced in the [aforementioned commit](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/commit/46cdb7f470f4e0452fc662f97bad1f6e2a174e0d), you first need to assembly `log4j-core-java9` and then use the dependency in the build process of `log4j-core` itself.

In a nutshell, try the following.

First, `log4j2` uses [`toolchains`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) in its build process, so for JDK 11 you may need to provide an entry in `~/.m2/toolchains.xml` file like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<toolchains>
  <!-- other definitions -->
  <toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
      <version>11</version>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <jdkHome>path/to/the/jdk (/opt/java/openjdk, for instance)</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
</toolchains>
```

You can find different toolchain configuration examples in the repository library.

Now, run the following commands from the directory in which you unpacked the library.

Install `log4j2-api-java9`:

```
cd log4j2-api-java9
../mvnw clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

Install `log4j2-api`:

```
cd ../log4j2-api
../mvnw clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

Install `log4j-core-java9`:

```
cd ../log4j-core-java9/
../mvnw clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

Finally, package `log4j-core`:

```
cd ../log4j-core
../mvnw clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

Please, be aware that this build process could generate a lot of artifacts that will be installed in your Maven local repository, and that may conflict with versions of the library downloaded from the Maven remote repository. Consider using for this process a temporary docker container, for example:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest
```

and run these different commands within it.

Comment: I removed the relevant `java9` entries from the `pom.xml`, and now `mvn compile` **finishes fine**. But I can't find any jar, just class files. Am I (still?) missing something?

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @OrenIshShalom. Yes, removing the java9 dependencies is certainly a possible workaround. It makes sense: you need to actually generate the jar artifacts: `mvn compile` just compiles the source code and generate the class files, but you need to run `mvn package` to generate the actual library jar files. Please, consider read the [Maven lifecycle documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). Please, could you try?

Comment: Apparently, both `mvn install -DskipTests` and `mvn package -DskipTests` fail with `(unpack-classes) on project log4j-core: Either artifact or artifactItems is required`

Comment: Probably it has to do with the fact that the java9 dependencies are required by the `maven-dependency-plugin` as configured in `pom.xml`. Please, see the updated answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Hallelujah ! It works ! Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome @OrenIshShalom! I am very happy to hear that it worked properly.